# matChip with cancel icon can't be removed and displays differently

Tags: angular, angular-material, icons, angular-material-7, md-chip

Actual: [the chip can't be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jllQ2.png)
Expected: [chip can be removed once you click x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fQOz.png)

I have done the following actions:

1. Imported MatIconModule and MatChipsModule in the main app.module. The module with my codes is a Child module/lazy loading. I need to import MatIconModule also in the Child component for the icon to work.

> import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';

2. Added the following in index.html

> link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"

3. Added the ff in style.css and updated angular.json file.

> @import "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
>
> "styles": [ "src/assets/css/style.css"]    //angular.json

4. Installed hammer

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ..

1. Install Angular Material Correctly 
   https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started
2. Import Font Family in styles.css

   @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");
3. This Code Will Do the rest

   ```
    <mat-chip-list>
      <mat-chip  (removed)="remove(event)"
        (click)="selected(event)">
         <i matChipRemove class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
      </mat-chip>
   ```